# Flux<String> returns a single string, where Mono<List<String>> returns an array. Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I have a method where I want to return a List of string. So I naturally use `Flux<String>`, but this returns a concatenated string.
When I use `.collectList()` to return a `Mono<List<String>>`, I get the array, but I find this dirty.

The code :

```
@Override
public Flux<String> uploadFiles(GcpFolderEnum type, Flux<FilePart> files) {
    if (FileUploadEnum.GCP.equals(fileUploadProperties.getType())) {
        return files.flatMap(file -> this.gcpServices.pushToBucket(type, file, file.filename())
                .map(this.gcpServices::getUrlCdnFromBucket));
    }

    return Flux.empty();
}
```

I am using java 11

Comment: How did you verify that `Flux<String>` returns a single string? From your question description it seems like the `Flux<String>` is behaving correctly as it emits every string/URL individually. (It's not a List!)

Comment: This help: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22662